# VSTS Yaml vraiables and path contradicting with classic editor

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am facing an issue when setting VSTS `classic editor` parameters when compare with current `yaml` file which is working as expected.

Below is working fine (Build pipeline)

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: "Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      inputs: 
        contents: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/**'
        targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "dotnet e2e tests"
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests
        zipAfterPublish: false
```

But same setting as per below find 0 files

```
2019-04-06T10:02:57.5303667Z found 0 files
2019-04-06T10:02:57.5376614Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

I have changed the `/` to `\` as well, but same outcome.

**Below is designer pipeline**

[image]

Same results in `dotnet publish` task also in `Path to project(s)` parameter `**\**\*.csproj`gives below error, but above `yaml` file works as expected.

```
2019-04-06T10:02:58.7896707Z ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
```

Comment: Since the second one is `release` pipeline, cannot use same paths as `build` pipeline?

Comment: Where do you check all the detail logging for above release tasks?

Comment: The designer is release pipeline?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk  yes it is

Comment: So this is the reason, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the release pipeline the variables `Build.SorucesDirectory` and `Build.ArtifactSatgingDirectory` are not available, these variables are only for build pipelines.

In fact, in the release agent folder there is not "Soruces" folder, but only "Artifact" folder. for example: `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`, the variable to get the value is: `System.ArtifactDirectory` or `Agent.ReleaseDirectory`.

More details about release variables you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables).